# Average in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm having problem with the Average column.  I must gave an average of each course.  With this XSLT I'm having the `NaN` for result.

Here is my XML file:

```
 <universite>
 <etudiant><name>Roger Tremblay</nom>
 <cours sigle="INF8430" note="89" />
 <cours sigle="INF1030" note="69" />
 <cours sigle="INF1230" note="75" /></etudiant>
 <etudiant><nom>Martin Lambert</nom>
 <cours sigle="INF8430" note="75" />
 <cours sigle="INF1030" note="72" />
 <cours sigle="INF1230" note="73" /></etudiant>
 <etudiant><nom>Luc Alain</nom>
 <cours sigle="INF9430" note="39" />
 <cours sigle="INF1030" note="89" />
 <cours sigle="INF1230" note="79" /></etudiant>
 <etudiant><nom>Olive Saint-Amant</nom>
 <cours sigle="INF8430" note="91" />
  <cours sigle="INF1230" note="99" /></etudiant>
 </universite>
```

And my XSLT file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
 <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:key name="montableau" match="cours" use="@sigle"/>
 <xsl:template match="universite">
 <html><body>
 <table border="1">
  <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
        <th style="text-align:left">Sigle</th>
        <th style="text-align:left">Nombre d'étudiants</th>
        <th style="text-align:left">Moyenne du cours</th>
      </tr>
   <xsl:for-each select="//cours" >
   <xsl:sort select="@sigle" order="ascending" data-type="text" />
  <xsl:if test="generate-id(.)=generate-id(key('montableau',@sigle)[1])">
  <tr>
     <td><xsl:value-of  select="@sigle" /></td>
     <td><xsl:value-of  select="count(//cours[@sigle=current()/@sigle])" /></td>
     <td><xsl:value-of select="sum(//cours[@note=current()/@note]) div count(//cours[@note=current()/@note])"/></td>
      </tr>
</xsl:if>
 </xsl:for-each>
 </table>
</body></html>
 </xsl:template>
 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Can you help me please?
Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Which average, the average number of students taking the course or the average note?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you should use:

```
<xsl:value-of select="sum(//cours[@sigle=current()/@sigle]/@note) div count(//cours[@sigle=current()/@sigle])"/>
```

or more efficiently:

```
<xsl:value-of select="sum(key('montableau', @sigle)/@note)
div count(key('montableau', @sigle))"/>
```

instead of:

```
<xsl:value-of select="sum(//cours[@note=current()/@note]) div count(//cours[@note=current()/@note])"/>
```